# Can`t plot data after a for

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I`m trying to plot an arrange vs the result of an equation using the arrange data. I am getting this error:

> NameError: name 'N' is not defined

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0.01, 4.5, 0.01)

for i in T:
    N = (2.63*10**-16)*((2.71828**(6.93*i))-1)+((4.05*10**-6)*i)

plt.plot (N,T) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) incorrectly.  The third parameter is the number of steps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0.01, 4.5, 450)
N = (2.63 * 10 ** -16) * ((2.71828 ** (6.93 * T)) - 1) + (
        (4.05 * 10 ** -6) * T)

plt.plot(N, T)
plt.show()
```

Also you do not need the `for` loop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Rauch mentioned, the third argument of `linspace` is [number of points](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). So with a `num` smaller than 1, `T` is empty and `N` is not assigned:

```
import numpy as np

T = np.linspace(0.01, 4.5, 0.01)
print(len(T)) # results 0
```

with [`Numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) you can define start, stop and step as:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.arange(0.01, 4.5, 0.01)
N = (2.63*10**-16)*((2.71828**(6.93*T))-1)+((4.05*10**-6)*T)

plt.plot (N,T) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you need to use `linspace` correctly, if you are wondering how to make the for loop work, one way is to use lists to store your values and then plot the list all at once.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0.01, 4.5, 450)
N = []

for i in T:
    N.append((2.63*10**-16)*((2.71828**(6.93*i))-1)+((4.05*10**-6)*i))

plt.plot (N,T) 
plt.show()
```